# Asking questions about the command line

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Is this the best site to be asking about the Android command line? Because many of the commands are different than on my Unix-like system.

Answer (score 6):

It depends a little. IMHO it is clearly on-topic as long as it is user-oriented (and not development-oriented), even it might be a "power-user's terrain". And even more on-topic if it's clearly something Android specific (as you've already indicated, many commands are "a little different", e.g. not all options are available to them).

But as you've asked for "the best site", there's also a second point to consider: If it's a generic quesion on available commands, or how to deal with things like redirecting output, piping, listing directories etc., that might fit better on either [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (at least you should *check* the questions there before, as you might find yours already answered).

Comment: @lzzy - I almost posted a developer answer here ... without veering off topic too much, which Stack Exchange site would be the correct one for developer command line questions specific to android, would that be StackOverflow ?

Comment: That very much depends on the question itself. If it can be phrased to represent a power-user's concern, it fits on ASE. If not, but rather is at e.g. integrating it with some app, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) is the better place (note the tag the link points to). Difficult to give a straight generic answer on that.

Answer (score 3):

I would have to say that this is definitely the right place to be asking about the command line, especially when it is Android specific.

[Can I trigger a media scan via the command line?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51784/can-i-trigger-a-media-scan-via-the-the-command-line/)